# setting values to Nan does not work in Pandas based on some Condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to set values to Nan in a data frame based on a column value. I've tried  some methods suggested on the Web but non of them actually setting the values to Nan for that particular column.
Following is some data for understanding purpose.

```
| user_id        | produc_id_x | rating_x | product_id_y | rating_y |
|----------------|-------------|----------|--------------|----------|
| A3G70XRVGQJSD4 | NaN         | NaN      | B0000DC3TN   | 2.0      |
| A392RM05V6KJ4B | B003AI2VGA  | 3.0      | B00004CQYO   | 4.0      |
| A7JI1GQJ9KYUA  | Nan         | Nan      | Q700063BT0   | 4.0      |
| A3GZWYWL3BQDLI | Nan         | Nan      | B003A3R3ZY   | 5.0      |
| A141HP4LYPWMSR | B003AI2VGA  | 3.0      | B002LMSWNC   | 3.0      |
```

> What requirement is that I want to set rating_y to Nan where
>   product_id_x is Nan:

This is the code that I've written for this purpose but It's not setting values to Nan

```
 masterDf=data.merge(data2,on="user_id",how="outer")
 #masterDf contains the complete dataframe

 masterDf.loc[masterDf['product_id_x']=='Nan','rating_y']='Nan'
```

Also this:

```
masterDfnan= masterDf.where(masterDf['product_id_x']=='Nan')
masterDfnan['rating_y']='Nan'
```

Also tried some other methods but None of them are working possibly.
Please help, Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this you may get your desired result:

```
masterDf.loc[masterDf['product_id_x'] == 'Nan', 'rating_y'] = np.nan
```

By doing this, you will result something like this:

```
| user_id        | produc_id_x | rating_x | product_id_y | rating_y |
|----------------|-------------|----------|--------------|----------|
| A3G70XRVGQJSD4 | NaN         | NaN      | B0000DC3TN   | Nan      |
| A392RM05V6KJ4B | B003AI2VGA  | 3.0      | B00004CQYO   | 4.0      |
| A7JI1GQJ9KYUA  | Nan         | Nan      | Q700063BT0   | Nan      |
| A3GZWYWL3BQDLI | Nan         | Nan      | B003A3R3ZY   | Nan      |
| A141HP4LYPWMSR | B003AI2VGA  | 3.0      | B002LMSWNC   | 3.0      |
```

Try this if it doesn't help. Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried numpy `np.nan`? (first `import numpy as np`)

If your 'Nan' is a string do something like:

```
masterDf[cols] = masterDf[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce')
```

After that or if your 'Nans' already are np.nan

```
masterDf.loc[masterDf['product_id_x'].isnull(),'rating_y'] = np.nan
```

Comment: what is cols in masterDf[cols]?

Comment: try this before use cols:  cols = masterDf.columns[masterDf.dtypes.eq('object')]

Comment: Can you help me here please  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54898862/how-to-deal-with-multiple-file-in-python